# php UPDATE is crazy

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to load massive data but I can't even load the first line in phpMyAdmin
[image]

What's wrong?

Comment: What is the datatype of dni?

Comment: it is int(11) and Parcial1 is decimal(4,2)

Comment: I found what it was. The update line were generated by Online Excel by concatenation of text and cell value of Parcial1 and dni. Then I copied and paste the output to a text editor and save it with sql extension. The sql code is correct, the only problem is the space between the number and WHERE as you can see indicated colored in magenta. I deleted the space and recreate again with space bar of keyboard and the error disappeared. That space comes because in that cell I wrote the text * WHERE `dni` =* with a leading space before WHERE. I don't know why is that causing the problem. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Enclose `3.5` within single quotes, it's not an integer.

Comment: nop, ``3.5``, '3.5', 3.50 didn't work, same error message

Comment: I'd also rather to use `WHERE dni LIKE 300`. Don't know if it would help though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE alumnos_svm SET Parcial1 = '3,5' WHERE dni = 300;
```

There can be a problem of Locale. If You use American locale, there is a chance, that your numbers are interpreted incorrectly - decimal separator is not ".", but ","